# adalProvider.init(..) breaking routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure, adal, adal.js

So per [this tutorial and working example](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-angular/), I previously had this function call in my app.js file (in which routing works perfectly fine):

```
app
    .config([
            '$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider',
            function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, adalProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/home',
                        {
                            templateUrl: '/app/views/home.html',
                            caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                        })
                    .when('/passwordReset',
                        {
                            templateUrl: '/app/views/passwordReset.html',
                            controller: 'ResetRequestController as vm',
                            requireAdLogin: true,
                            caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                        })
                    .when('/userSearch',
                        {
                            templateUrl: '/app/views/userSearch.html',
                            controller: 'UserSearchController as vm',
                            requireAdLogin: true,
                            caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                        })
                    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });

            }
        ]
    );
```

...But by adding the following code as the tutorial requests and adding this line (directly after `.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });`:

```
adalProvider.init(
    {
        instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
        tenant: '...', //Removed
        clientId: '...', //Removed
        extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
        //cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
    },
    $httpProvider
);
```

...I get the following errors:

> angular.js:13424 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template:
>   app/views/_header.html (HTTP status: undefined undefined)
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$compile/tpload?p0=app%2Fviews%2F_header.html&p1=undefined&p2=undefined
>       at angular.js:68
>       ...[truncated by user for readability]
>
> angular.js:13424 TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
>       at routeChangeHandler (adal-angular.js:213)
>       ...[truncated by user for readability]
>
> angular.js:13424 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template:
>   /app/views/home.html (HTTP status: undefined undefined)
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$compile/tpload?p0=%2Fapp%2Fviews%2Fhome.html&p1=undefined&p2=undefined
>       at angular.js:68
>       ...[truncated by user for readability]

Multiple StackOverflow questions already address error message #1 and #3, but they suggest confirming that the routes are correct. Not only did I confirm that the files are there (via directly pointing the browser at them), but as previously mentioned simply not having the `adalProvider.init(..)` the routes return to normal.

I'm running the latest version of adal.js and adal-angular.js included in the npm package version 1.0.10.

What am I missing here? What can I correct to return routing to working order while still implementing `adalProvider.init(..)`?

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar problem with Angular / Adal.js. I am using ui-router instead of ng-route, tried swapping to ng-route to see if this would fix the problem (figured it had something to do with resolving the template URIs), but the issue remained. I think my solution could work for you as well, since it doesn't seem related to the routing but to the adal config.

Updated my config with anonymous endpoints, the partials which are not shielded by authentication:

```
    var anonymousEndpoints = [
      'partials/public/'
    ];

    var endpoints = {
      // Map the location of a request to an API to a the identifier of the associated resource
      'https://contosotogo.azurewebsites.net/': 'https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/ToGoAPI'
    };

 adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init(
   {
     tenant: '__removed__',
     clientId: '__removed__',
     anonymousEndpoints: anonymousEndpoints, // Added this
     endpoints: endpoints
   },
   $httpProvider
 );
```

I figure the templates are stored in Angulars templatecache via an unknown key/status and cannot be retrieved while not authenticated. Since they don't need authentication, I've pulled them out. This also seems to have solved the infinite looping problem while renewing expired tokens (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/216).

Honestly, I've been facing a lot of issues implementing adal.js. Getting stuff to work has been an effort scouring stackoverflow/github and the odd tutorial/example...

Hope it helps, cheers

Comment: Hello, I am still facing same issue, my route is not working after I enable init.

I have added endpoints and anonymousEndpoints as follows 

var anonymousEndpoints = [
      'requeue/app/template/'
    ];
var endpoints = {
      // Map the location of a request to an API to a the identifier of the associated resource
      'https://contosotogo.azurewebsites.net/': 'https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/ToGoAPI'
    };

Now am getting error as follows 
angular.js:14700 TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null(…) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"

Can you please help me on this?